# How to shared terminal state and variables between dependent vscode tasks

Tags: vscode-tasks

I am using VS Code tasks to run a python script, and I need to first activate a specific Conda environment. So I can reuse the `conda activate` function in multiple tasks, I would like to activate a specific conda environment in one task and then run scripts in other tasks with the "conda activate" task as a dependency.

However, the following example doesn't appear to work as I expected. When I activate a conda environment in the dependent task, the main task can't "see" the activated environment. I set `"panel"="shared"`, but that doesn't seem to make a difference in my case.

For example

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "activate_myEnv",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "eval \"$(conda shell.bash hook)\" && conda activate myEnv && which python",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "which_python",
            "dependsOn": ["activate_myEnv"],
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "which python",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            }
        },

}
```

When I run the `which_python` task, the ouptut is:

```sh
> Executing task: eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)" && conda activate myEnv && which python <

/home/blaylock/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/bin/python  #<-- myEnv is successfully activated

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: which python <

/home/blaylock/anaconda3/envs/base/bin/python   #<-- But the second task reverts to the base conda environment.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Maybe I misunderstood what `"panel"="shared"` (which is the default) does, but I expected my second task to recognize that I have changed conda environments.

---

##### Edit

In this a more simplistic example, I have set variable `a` in one task, and try to print it in a subsequent task, but the value isn't known...

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "set_var_a",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "a=5 && echo a=$a",
        },
        {
            "label": "echo_a",
            "dependsOn": ["set_var_a"],
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo a=$a",
        }
}
```

The oupt of running the `echo_a` task

```sh
> Executing task: a=5 && echo a=$a <

a=5

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: echo a=$a <

a=

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Again, I would have expected the second task to recognize variables set in the dependent task.